# Why is raising by $(p-1)/2$ not always equal to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$? (Manipulating powers modulo p)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

tl;dr: why is raising by $(p-1)/2$ not always equal to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$?

I was studying the proof of why generators do not have quadratic residues and I stumbled in one step on the proof that I thought might be a good question that might help other people in the future when raising powers modulo $p$.

Let $p$ be prime and as usual, $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ be the integers mod $p$ with inverses.

Consider raising the generator $g$ to the power of $(p-1)/2$:

$$g^{(p-1)/2}$$

then, I was looking for a somewhat rigorous argument (or very good intuition) on why that was **not always** equal to $1$ by fermat's little theorem (when I say always, I mean, even when you do NOT assume the generator has a quadratic residue).

i.e. why is this logic flawed:

$$ g^{(p-1)/2} = (g^{(p-1)})^{\frac{1}{2}} = (1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ (mod \ p)$$

to solve the last step find an x such that $1 = x \ (mod \ p)$. $x$ is obviously $1$, which completes the wrong proof that raising anything to $(p-1)/2$ is always equal to $1$. This obviously should not be the case, specially for a generator since the only power that should yield $1$ for a generator is $p-1$, otherwise, it can't generate one of the elements in the cyclic set.

The reason that I thought that this was illegal was because you can only raise to powers of integers mod $p$ and $1/2$ is obviously not valid (since its not an integer). Also, if I recall correctly, not every number in a set has a k-th root, right? And $1/2$ actually just means square rooting...right? Also, maybe it was a notational confusion where to the power of $1/2$ actually just means a function/algorithm that "finds" the inverse such that $z = x^2 \ (mod \ p)$. So is the illegal step claiming that you can separate the powers because at that step, you would be raising to the power of an element not allowed in the set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $1$ has **two** square roots modulo $p$ if $p\gt 2$.

So from $g^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, we conclude that 
$$\left(g^{(p-1)/2}\right)^2\equiv 1\pmod{p},$$
and therefore 
$$g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}.$$

If $g$ is a primitive root of $p$, and $p\gt 2$, then $g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is not possible, so $g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: $g^{(p−1)/2}≡1 \ (mod \ p)$ is not possible because g is a generator and p-1/2 <p-1 and only an exponent of p-1 should generate 1, since otherwise, g wouldn't be a correct generator?

Comment: My answer in essence consisted of parts: (i) If $g$ is **any** number not divisible by $p$, then $g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$, (ii) If furthermore $g$ is a generator, and $p\gt 2$, then $g^{(p-1)/2}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. This last is for the reason you give: If we had $g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1$, that would contradict the fact that the generator $g$ has order $p-1$. Essentially what you wrote above.

Answer (score 3):

You've attempted to apply a method of computing $k$-th roots outside its domain of applicability.

It *is* true that if $\,(k,p\!-\!1) = 1\,$ then $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!-\!1\!:\ \,k^{-1}\! = \color{#c00}{1/k \equiv i}\,$ exists, so $\ g^{\Large{j/k}} \equiv (g^{\Large j})^{\large{ \color{#c00}{1/k}}} \equiv g^{\Large j\color{#c00}i}.$

But this does not apply in your case $\,k =2\ $ since $\,2\mid p\!-\!1\,$ so $\,(k,p\!-\!1) = (2,p\!-\!1) = 2\ne 1$.

Essentially you are attempting to invert  $\,2\,$ in the ring $\,\Bbb Z/(p\!-\!1),\,$ where $\,2\,$ is a *zero-divisor*, since $\,2\mid p\!-\!1.\, $ This is a sort of ring-theoretic generalization of the sin of dividing by zero, since the only ring with an invertible zero-divisor is the trivial ring $\{0\}.$

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you are saying that if gcd(k,p-1)=1, then it has a 1/k'th root? And the case when 2|p-1 doesn't apply since p-1 is even?

Comment: Yes, as I explained, $\, a^{\large \color{#c00}{1/k}} \equiv a^{\large \color{#c00}i},\,$ when $\,k\,$ is coprime to $\,p-1.$

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Thanks! That makes so much more sense now! Sorry, I just had a little difficulty parsing that line since everything was just compressed into one big long line.

Answer (score 2):

Taking roots in modular arithmetics doesn't work.

For example check this:

$9 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$, but $2 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$, doesn't hold.

Now to the problem. If $(g,p) = 1$, then

$$g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod p \text {    or    } g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$$

This is because:

$$g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
$$g^{p-1} - 1\equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$(g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} - 1)(g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} + 1) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Obviously only one of the factors can be 0 modulo $p$.

Comment: Just to make it clear, is $g^{(p−1)/2}≡1 \ (mod \ p)$ not possible because g is a generator and p-1/2 <p-1 and only an exponent of p-1 should generate 1, since otherwise, g wouldn't be a correct generator?

Comment: @Pinocchio I just said that $(g,p) = 1$, so the modulo can be either $-1$ or $1$. And of course I left some work for you to do and as I can see you've done that.

Also it would be better to use the term primitive root rather than generator.

Comment: why is the term primitive root better? (for me, its the first time I have even read it, so I wanted to learn why its a good term and how to use it). Btw, thanx! :)

Comment: Primitive root means the same as generator, but in my opinion primitive root is much more commonly used term.